# add custom css to navigation tab wizard

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, frontend

I need to highlight selected tabs in the navigation tab wizard. tab functionality is working fine..but I need to add the CSS(border-style) for all the selected tab. for example, if I have 4 tabs. If I have selected the first and second tab(next button) those tab needs to be highlighted(apply border) and again if I click the back button the highlight needs to be removed.Any help would be appreciated. please find the image below for reference.

```js
        
public tabs: string[] = ['tab1', 'tab2', 'tabs3', 'tabs4']   
public next(): void {
    const currentIndex: number = this.tabs.indexOf(this.selectedTab);
    const newIndex = currentIndex + 1;
    this.selectedTab = this.tabs[newIndex];
  }

  public back(): void {
    const currentIndex: number = this.tabs.indexOf(this.selectedTab);
    const newIndex = currentIndex - 1;
    this.selectedTab = this.tabs[newIndex];
  }
```

```css
.tab-highlight { 
    border-top: 2px solid blue;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs side_nav" role="tablist">
<li *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let i= index;" [attr.data-index]="i" role="presentation"
            class="accounts_li"
            [class.active]="selectedTab===tab" (click)="toggle($event)">
          <a (click)="selectedTab = tab" aria-controls="one" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">{{tab}}</a>
        </li></ul>
        
        <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab1" *ngIf="selectedTab === tabs[0]" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active">
        tab1 content
        </div>
        
          <div id="tab2" *ngIf="selectedTab === tabs[1]" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active">
        tab2 content
        </div>
          <div id="tab3" *ngIf="selectedTab === tabs[2]" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active">
    tab3 content
    </div>
        </div>

<button class="button" (click)="back()"><span>
            Back</span>
          </button>
          
          <button class="button" (click)="next()"><span>
           Next</span>
          </button>
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cY8r.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select multiple tabs then you should change the `selectedTab` property with an array which will hold all selected tabs. Then you could create a method which will check if the tab is selected or not in order to push/remove from the selected array. Lastly, for the conditional class name you could use `[ngClass]="isSelected(tab) ? 'tab-highlight' : null"`, this will add the class only if the condition is evaluated to true (more on this here https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

Component code:

```
  tabs: string[] = ["tab1", "tab2", "tab3", "tab4"];
  selectedTabs: string[] = [];

  onTabClick(tab) {
    if (this.isSelected(tab)) {
      let index = this.selectedTabs.indexOf(tab);
      this.selectedTabs.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      this.selectedTabs.push(tab);
    }
  }

  isSelected(tab: string) {
    return this.selectedTabs.indexOf(tab) > -1;
  }
```

HTML code for the tab menu:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs side_nav" role="tablist">
    <li *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let i= index;" [attr.data-index]="i" role="presentation"
        [ngClass]="isSelected(tab) ? 'tab-highlight' : null">
        <a (click)="onTabClick(tab)" aria-controls="one" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">{{tab}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/question63192497?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts